# Eclipse not recognising numberPassword when set to Android 4.0?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, textview

The Eclipse editor isn't recognising the inputType on a field when I put it as "numberPassword", here's the code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pin_field"
    android:layout_width="236dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberPassword">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Here's the error I get on the "android:inputType" line:

```
"error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'inputType' with value 'numberPassword')."
```

And in the 'Graphical Layout' tab at the top I've changed the version from 2.3.3 up to Android 4.0 which I read might fix it but it doesn't seem to have worked. I'm probably missing something obvious but can't figure it out.

Here's the Android documentation for inputType and 'numberPassword': http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputType

Comment: Project's Android build target set to 4.0?

Comment: can you post the AndroidManifest file.

Comment: The API level is set to 14, I'll post the manifest up now.

Comment: Doh. Knew it'd be something obvious. I had the projects build target in Eclipse set to 2.3.3 but the minSdk in the Manifest file as API level 14 which is 4.0 and that threw me off. An easy 50 rep for you dispake if you post it as an answer. I need to actually test it which I can't do till Monday but if it works I'll accept your answer then.

Comment: It works dispake, post it up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispake's comment gave me the clue I needed

> "Project's Android build target set to 4.0?"

I had the minSdk in the Manifest file as API level 14 which is 4.0 and correct, that threw me off finding the real problem. I had the project's build target in Eclipse set to 2.3.3 which needed to be changed to 4.0.

Comment: 2.3.3 Changed to what?

Comment: @Mr.Noob I think it was 4.0 that was needed for numberPassword.

Comment: Cheers dude. It comes on android 3.0 and above only :) Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pin_field"
    android:layout_width="236dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:password="true"
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Try the above code instead of you code

or you can dynamically set through code as below

```
editText.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Updated::
Through code set InputFilter like below to  accept only alphabets or numeric or both

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
            if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                return src;
            }
            if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")){
                return src;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
});
```

please test thoroughly though !

Comment: I think this method would mean that you get the . # etc. at the side which I don't want for my application. I upvoted anyway as I think your method will be useful in the future with the :password="true" bit.

Comment: I needed the "numberPassword" field to work as I state in the question. I could filter the input but I didn't really want to have to do that when Android already provides a keyboard without anything but numbers on it. The keyboard without any numbers was what I wanted working. Your code may work but it turns out the problem was I'd set the build level wrong for project which dispake pointed out in the comments so he fixed my problem. Thanks for the help anyway, and if dispake doesn't post his answer you'll still get half the bounty.

Comment: Looks like Dispake isn't going to post his answer up so I'll accept yours, I think it could prove useful in future.

Comment: You dont require actually those two conditions in `inputfilter` as even if first condition is true you going to return `""` string, so you can freely remove first if condition as its when user input `"A"` then also without need it going to test that condition and waste time :) correct me if i am wrong.!!

Comment: `android:password` is now deprecated